# Generating function for Catalan numbers using the "Analytic combinatorics" approach.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

So, I first learnt about how to go from the recurence relation of the Catalan numbers to their generating function from exercise 12-4 of the book, Introduction to Algorithms, third edition by Cormen et.al. Here, they define the recurrence relation:

$$b_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}b_k b_{n-k-1}\tag{1}$$

And after some non-trivial amount of algebra, we conclude that the generating function $B(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$ (edit here: changed to $z^n$) satisfies:

$$B(z)=1+zB(z)^2\tag{2}$$ finally yielding the closed-form:

$$B(z)= \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\tag{3}$$

Cormen et.al. do this in the context of counting the number of binary trees with $n$ nodes. In figure 12.1, it seems apparent to me that they define a Binary tree as a tree where each node has 0, 1 or 2 children and one node has the special status of the "root".

Now, I was going through the course by Robert Sedgewick on Analytic Combinatorics (Coursera; it's a free course). It follows the textbook of the same name (0th edition). Here, they reach the same generating function in equation (2) in just one step. On page 6, they do this for trees "with $n$ binary branching nodes hence $n+1$ external nodes". They then write the symbolic equation:

$$C=e+(C,n,C)\tag{4}$$

where $e$ denotes the external nodes and $n$ the internal nodes. Defining the "size" of $e$ to be $1$ they get directly the the generating function in (2):

$$C(z)=1+zC(z)^2$$

Then, on page 62, they define the concept of "unary-binary" trees that can have $0$, $1$ or $2$ child nodes and come up with a different generating function for them.

Now for my questions:

1. I thought the tree-structures Cormen et.al. were considering were "unary-binary" trees as seemed evident from figure 12.1. What is the difference between these trees (which Sedgewick describes as trees with $n$ internal nodes) and unary binary trees?
2. Why do we need this concept of external nodes to construct equation (4)? What if I was doing this from scratch and never thought of external nodes? Is there a corresponding symbolic equation that can lead to the generating function if I never thought of external nodes (like Cormen et.al. didn't consider them)?

Answer (score 1):

The two variants of tree are equivalent in that if
you have a Sedgewick tree and remove all external
nodes you get a Cormen tree. Conversely, if you have
a *non-empty* Cormen tree, then each node that does *not* have
two children has the missing children added to it, while the empty Cormen tree acquires a
root node.

In equation $(4)$ the $e$ represents the tree
with only one node which is an external node.
The $n$ represents the root node which is an
internal node in case there is more than one
node.

The interpretation for Cormen trees of the
same equation would be that $e$ represents
the empty tree with $0$ nodes and $n$ is
again the root node.

In both kinds of binary trees, the children
nodes are distinguished as being **left** or **right**. Thus, in the Cormen tree with a
root node and one child, there is a left child version and a right child version. In the case
of "unary-binary" trees, the unary child is
only one kind.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was about the distinction with unary-binary trees as Sedgewick describes them. I think I'm seeing now (vaguely) the difference lies in the shape. While the binary trees will have nodes that will always have a .left and .right attribute (which can be None), the unary-binary trees might have nodes that have just a single child.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, the $1$ in $(2)$ accounts for the value of $C_0$; this is necessary, since the rest of $(2)$ has a $0$ constant term. Similarly, when we count full binary trees with $n$ internal nodes, we have to account for the unique one with no internal nodes, since for this class the size is the number of internal nodes. Thus, we necessarily get $\mathcal{B}=\{\epsilon\}+\mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{Z}\times\mathcal{B}$ and $B(z)=1+zB(z)^2$.

In both cases we have to account for the size $0$ case separately: in the algebraic derivation from the recurrence it accounts for the initial condition, and in the symbolic approach it accounts it essentially does the same thing, since the tree of size $0$ is the only one that isn’t built up via the product $\mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{Z}\times\mathcal{B}$ that describes hanging two binary trees from a ‘root’ node.

Comment: Thanks. Quick follow up question - what if in the Catalan sequence, I defined $C_0=0$ instead of 1, keeping the rest of the terms the same. Would I be able to exclude the $1$ then from equation (2)? If I do that, I get $B(z)=\frac{1}{z}$

Comment: For the symbolic case, this would be equivalent to saying that if there are no nodes, we don't consider it a tree.

Comment: @RohitPandey: In that case the recurrence generates the $0$ sequence, and the generating function is simply $f(z)=0$. And $B(z)=0$ is clearly one of the solutions when you drop the $e$ in $(4)$; I’m not sure whether the other is actually meaningful.

Comment: Got it. I feel like setting $C_0=0$ is also a natural thing to do if someone were investigating many of the combinatoric objects the Catalan numbers represent from scratch. So it's unsatisfying that in that case, the generating function doesn't lead to the sequence. Or maybe it does and we need some additional tricks. We know in reality, the generating function is simply $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}-1$

Comment: @RohitPandey: No, the generating function is $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$, because $C_0=1$. And in this case setting $C_0=1$ is far more natural: there is one Dyck path of length $0$, one well-formed parenthesis string with no parentheses, one full binary tree with no internal nodes, etc.

Comment: I recently asked a question about generalizing Dyck paths such that instead of *crossing* the main diagonal $0$ times, the paths cross the main diagonal exactly $k$ times ($k$ can be 0 in which case we get 2 times the Dyck paths). I called these paths $R_{k,n}$. If $C_0=1$ is natural, what is a natural choice for $R_{k,0}$ when $k \neq 0$? The answers ended up ignoring that case by making the generating function start at $n=1$.

Comment: @RohitPandey: Assuming that you mean *cross* and not just *touch*, I’d say that $R_{k,0}=0$ when $k\ne 0$. But it may well be easier to deal with all cases simultaneously if one simply starts one’s power series at $n=1$.

Comment: Makes sense. That's what I thought too. Sorry, one last thing - in general, we had $R_{0,n}=2C_n$. This is because we count paths that stay above or stay below the main diagonal when they don't cross it. The rule seems to break down at $n=0$. If $C_0=1$, then $R_{0,0}$ should be $2$. But there is no way to make sense of this from a counting perspective. Defining $C_0=0$ on the other hand makes $R_{0,0}=0$ as well. Anyway, just wanted to share some background on why I thought $C_0=0$ might be somewhat justified in some contexts. Maybe there is another easy resolution I'm missing.